# Android - Keep notification steady at Notification Bar

Tags: android, notification-bar, android-notification-bar

I have written the function to notify and display at Notification bar:

```
private void showNotification()
    {
            CharSequence title = "Hello";
            CharSequence message = "Notification Demo";

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "A Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main_Activity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(Main_Activity.this, title, message, pendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

Its working fine, But **`what way we can keep the notification steady at Notification bar`** even when user press the "clear" notificatios button from the notification bar ?

Please have a look at the "Yahoo" application's notification bar.

[image]

I have gone through this SDK article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating , but failed to find out.

Comment: Are you sure keeping that notification steady is a good idea?

Comment: @Heiko Rupp sorry to say yes but its the actual requirement that i have to implement.

Comment: Readers should be clear on this: using this for advertising your app will annoy your users intensely and it should only be used for were you need to provide consistent quick access to control a running service.  Eg: a music app (only while something is playing), navigation (only while it's navigating a route) or GPS logger (while it's logging).

Comment: @couling agree with you, many advertising platform use this functionality and users are being interfered.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `FLAG_NO_CLEAR`

Just set it on your `Notification` instance before supplying it to the `NotificationManager`:

```
notificaton.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

*edit:* I just noticed though that if you are using `Notification.Builder` (since Honeycomb) and make the notification "ongoing", it will also become immune to "clear all". See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29).

Appearently, this is supposed to discourage developers from using the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` on a non-ongoing notificaton since this could confuse the user.

Answer (score 14):

Try  **setOngoing(true).**

```
notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
          .setLargeIcon(
                   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),     R.drawable.ic_launcher))
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setTicker(tickerText)
          .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
          .setOngoing(true)
          .setContentText(contentText)
          .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
```